# Mongoose (6.x) populate after save

Tags: node.js, mongoose, save, populate

In Mongoose 6 `execPopulate()` seemed to be removed. Due to this, the below code returns error.

```
const t = new MyModel(value)
return t.save().then(t => t.populate('my-path').execPopulate())
```

I'd like to know how to populate after save in Mongoose 6 or later. FYI, the newly created and unpopulated instance should be used before populating so I don't wanna use `MyModel.populate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is super easy. `populate()` itself returns the correct promise.

```
const t = new MyModel(value)
return t.save().then(t => t.populate('my-path'))
```

I was mistaken for not populating the relevant object, but I found it to work.